# Ajax call in custom SugarCrm Module returns html

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have a Custom module in Sugar Crm.

I have a custom controller which returns me data from the database. but when i make an ajax call to the controller i am also getting the html template along with the data.

is there any way in sugar crm where i can get only the data instead of the whole htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the URL for the AJAX call you are making, add the parameter to_pdf=1 to it to disable the HTML template.